# <Link> doesn't update component using React + Redux (not a dupe)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-v4

guys, first of all, it may look like a duplicate, but I swear, I searched all over the place and all the possible solutions didn't worked for me.

The problem is the classic "When I click on a  element the URL changes but the component doesn't update"

In fact, it updates, but only on the first click.

Here is my relevant code:

### index.js

```
...
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <div>
        <App />
      </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  target
);
```

### App component

```
...
const App = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route path="/items/:id" component={Product} />
                <Route path="/items" component={Search} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default App;
```

### Search component

```
...
const Search = props => (
    <div>
        <header>
            <SearchBar />
        </header>
        <main>
            <SearchResult />
        </main>
    </div>
);

export default Search;
```

### SearchResult component

```
const renderItem = result => (
  <div key={result.id} className="result-item">
    <Link to={`/items/${result.id}`}>
        ...
    </Link>
  </div>
);

class SearchResult extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    if (!this.props.resultIsLoading && !this.props.results.items) {
      const { search: term } = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search);
      this.props.search(term);
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.props.results.items) return <div>...</div>;

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="product-list">
          {this.props.results.items.map(renderItem)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ results, resultIsLoading }) =>
  ({ results, resultIsLoading });

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators({ search }, dispatch);

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchResult));
```

When I click the , the state doesn't change, the reducer is not called and the ProductDetails component doesn't update.

I've tried a lot of possible solutions. { pure: false } on connect, pass location as a prop, remove main BrowserRouter, remove withRouter, none seems to work.

Can, please, someone give me a light on this?

Comment: do you want to render a new component after click or the `SearchResult` Component is already rendered, you need to update the results

Comment: actualy the SearchResult component is a result list, each of the results have their own <Link> pointing to a Product Details page. If I click on the first <Link> everything works OK, but if I got back and click in another product, the first is still displayed, for ever, until I refresh page.

Comment: the ProductDetail component parse the URL and dispatch a action to load the correct product on the componenWillMount event. But this action is only called once.

Comment: You need to move `componentWillMount` code to `componentWillReceiveProps` with condition nextProps.id !== this.props.id

Comment: @PiyushBhati Followed your suggestion hoping it will help, but unfortunately it doesn't. The componentWillReceiveProps event is not even called when URL changes :-/

Comment: If possible, Can you create a fiddle of your code.. I can debug and let you know the root cause